# Postgres Django data disappearing from containerized services

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Below is the docker compose file which I used to launch two services, postgres database and django application.

Somehow, my data in postgres is disappearing. I am not sure whether it is a Django problem or Postgres problem.

It doesn't get disappear quickly, after couple of days suddenly I am seeing nothing in the database. Even the django superuser getting disappear.

But the docker services are still running. `docker compose ls` shows the services.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - PRODUCTION=false
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env.dev
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
        sh -c "/wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && 
              python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
    environment:
      - PRODUCTION=false
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env.dev
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: Look in the log file.